# Salesforce SOAP Integration

Tags: apex, integration, soap

```
Req :-  Custom Settings :-  Vacancy Media
                Fields:-   Name
                           Type
                           Area
                           Path
        Map -- mapvacancymedia1
```

i have created a map mapvacanymedia1 in which i am fetching the values from the above custom setting 
and i need to create an XML file for the same.

But i am geeting error as : SObject row does not allow errors

Please help me to generate the XML for the same.

Code as below.

```
  if(mapvacanymedia1.size()>0){
                        for(integer i=0;i<=vacancyMediaMapping.size();i++){
                            xmlW.writeStartElement(null,'VacancyMedia',null);
                            xmlW.writeStartElement(null,'Type',null);
                            xmlW.writeCharacters(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Client Logo').Type__c);
                            xmlW.writeStartElement(null,'Area',null);
                            xmlW.writeCharacters(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Job Video').Area__c);
                            xmlW.writeStartElement(null,'Path',null);
                            xmlW.writeCharacters(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Client Video').Path__c);
                            xmlW.writeEndElement();
                            System.debug('Debug at 743');
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please use relevant tags. This question is not related to `salesforce1-app` or `continuous-integration`.

Answer (score 2):

When using a generator, you need to make sure you close all the elements you open (each "writeStartElement" must be paired with a "writeEndElement"). Because this can get complicated, I generally recommend using [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) directly instead of using a generator. There are simply too many things that can go wrong. I don't want to take any presumptions about your data, but if you insist on using the generator, you need to remember to close each element you open.

---

## Example

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.XmlNode root = doc.createRootElement('demo',null,null);

...

Dom.XmlNode vacancyMediaNode = root.addChildElement('VacancyMedia',null,null);
Dom.XmlNode typeNode = vacancyMediaNode.addChileElement('Type',null,null);
typeNode.addTextNode(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Client Logo').Type__c);
Dom.XmlNode areaNode = vacancyMediaNode.addChildElement('Area',null,null);
areaNode.addTextNode(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Job Video').Area__c);
Dom.XmlNode pathNode = vacancyMediaNode.addChildElement('Path',null,null);
pathNode.addTextNode(vacancyMediaMapping.get('Client Video').Path__c);

...

String xmlString = doc.toXmlString();
```

Comment: Thanks !!! can you give me the any example how to use the Dom.Document??

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar you can find example here: [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar I added an example that shows how the parts might work. You'll need to do additional work as necessary.

Comment: Hi Currently i am not allowed to use the Dom.document ....as per project requirement , and after closing all the tab still i am getting the error "SObject row does not allow errors". Please help me out for this one.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar That error is not at all related to this code. Consider asking a new question so it can get appropriate attention.